# Using "#define" in a Header in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm  confused how to use #define, or if this is even what I want to be using.

I have a header file:

```
#define var     3;

int foo();

...(etc)
```

As well as two similarly structured files outside of it:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    printf("%i", var);
}
```

Am I wrong in thinking that I can use the var from the header in C files which include the header?

This is actually a part of homework, and I'm not permitted to change the header file. If I can't use it like this, is there some way to use the variable outside the file other than an accessor function?

Comment: `#define var 3;` is horrible, horrible C (especially that semicolon on the end). If this is the code you were provided, you should complain to the instructor...

Comment: `#define var     3;` Omit the ';'

Comment: But your header file is strange. The `;` after `3` should not be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't put a semicolon to the end of your defined value.
Instead of

```
#define var 3;
```

use

```
#define var 3
```

With your define the print statement is expanded to the following by the preprocessor:

```
printf("%i", 3;);
```

...that is invalid code.
The preprocessor doesn't really respect the rules of the C/C++ language, it's rather a barbar textual substitution tool, maybe a bit smarter than that but much more dumber than the C language itself...

If you are not allowed the change the header then you can still say

```
int my_variable = var
```

And you can even put any number of semicolons after the previous statement if you like that more.

Answer (score 1):

The header file needs to be properly defined:

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE
#define HEADER_FILE

#define var 3 // <-- no semi

#endif
```

Now depending on how you defined `var`, you should be able to do:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    printf("%i", var);
}
```